RStudio: obtener valor p con la función lmer
¡Hola! Estoy empleando la función lmer en RStudio para crear varios modelos de efectos mixtos y, al pedir el resumen de estos con la forma "summary(modelo)", me devuelve los efectos aleatorios y los efectos mixtos, pero para estos últimos no me indica el valor de p asociado al valor de t. He empleado estas mismas funciones antes y sí me indicaba el valor de p. ¿Alguien conoce el motivo? ¡Gracias!

Hola, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask],saludos.

¡Hola! Estoy analizando los tiempos de reacción de un estudio de lectura. En él tengo dos variables independientes y la fórmula que he empleado es esta: modelo=lmer(TR_BRUTO~VI1+VI2+VI1*VI2+(1+VI1+VI2|Sujeto) + (1+VI1+VI2|Item), data=R4, REML=FALSE). Al pedir el "summary" del modelo, devuelve para los efectos fijos la estimación, el error y el valor de t, pero no así el valor de p:

Esto es lo que me devuelve:Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    511.31      17.93  28.521
VI1hum          29.52      12.65   2.334
VI2sí           52.74      11.89   4.438
VI1hum:VI2sí   -21.98      15.69  -1.401

¡Hola! Estoy analizando los tiempos de reacción de un estudio de lectura. En él tengo dos variables independientes y la fórmula que he empleado es esta:

modelo=lmer(TR_BRUTO~VI1+VI2+VI1*VI2+(1+VI1+VI2|Sujeto) + (1+VI1+VI2|Item), data=R4, REML=FALSE).

Al pedir el "summary" del modelo, devuelve para los efectos fijos la estimación, el error y el valor de t, pero no así el valor de p:

Estimate Std.   Error      t       value
(Intercept)     511.31     17.93   28.521
VI1hum          29.52      12.65   2.334
VI2sí           52.74      11.89   4.438
VI1hum:VI2sí    -21.98     15.69   -1.401

No es la primera vez que aplico esta función y otras veces sí me devolvía el valor de p. No sé si hay algún error. Gracias.

Esto no responde a tu pregunta... si quieres editarla para añadir la información hay un enlace editar justo debajo de la pregunta que puedes usar. Esto no es un foro, aquí no sirve "hacer un nuevo post abajo" para añadir cosas
